# I want to write my everyday experience while living abroad

Tags: support, meta

I want to write my everyday experience while living abroad.

Does the expatriates.stackexchange.com have any blogging facility?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at our [help center](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help). As part of the Stack Exchange network, we are a question and answer site. So no, we do not have a blog, but if you have questions (or answers) please share them with us.

Comment: You can even ask a question & immediately answer it yourself - so if you happen across a situation which you think others might encounter, you could formulate a question about it and then answer it with your way of dealing with it.

Comment: One example of this already happening is this one: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/95/25 Note that there are actually more upvoted and better answers than the self answered one, so it does have it's merits